# SQL to build a quarterly table from 3 monthly records without grouping

Tags: sql, insert, ms-access-2010

I need to build a quarterly table in MS Access2010 that contains 3 repeating monthly columns, e.g., Month1_temp, Month2_temp, Month3_temp. My source data is a table that has one record per month.  Therefore I must read 3 monthly records in order to build a single quarterly record.
When I read a monthly source record, the "Month" value (1, 2, or 3) will determine which temp column will be populated in the target record.
The primary key in the target table is the concatenated "Location + Year + Qtr"

Example:
My monthly detail source data has fields as such;
   Primary_Key
   Location
   Year
   Qtr (values 1,2,3, or 4)
   Month (values 1,2, or 3)
   Temp

Target table would be: 
   Primary_Key
   Location
   Year
   Qtr
   Month1_Temp
   Month2_Temp
   Month3_Temp

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to tweak this for use with MS Acccess, but this should show you one possible idea:

```
INSERT INTO Summarry (Location,Year,Quarter,Month1_Temp,Month2_Temp,Month3_Temp)
SELECT a.Location,a.Year,a.Quarter,b.NumericValue,c.NumericValue,d.NumericValue
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT Location,Year,Quarter
FROM DetailSource
) a 

INNER JOIN 

(
SELECT Location,Year,Quarter,NumericValue
FROM DetailSource
WHERE Month = 1
) b ON (a.Location = b.Location AND a.Year = b.Year AND a.Quarter = b.Quarter)

INNER JOIN 

(
SELECT Location,Year,Quarter,NumericValue
FROM DetailSource
WHERE Month = 2
) c ON (a.Location = c.Location AND a.Year = c.Year AND a.Quarter = c.Quarter)

INNER JOIN 

(
SELECT Location,Year,Quarter,NumericValue
FROM DetailSource
WHERE Month = 3
) d ON (a.Location = d.Location AND a.Year = d.Year AND a.Quarter = d.Quarter)

WHERE a.Location = 'MyLocation' AND a.Year = 2015 AND a.Quarter = 1
```